# qstatus bar layout -- formatting

Tags: qt

My gui have a qmainwindow & with treeview on the left & right side their are some buttons & tableview in the middle of the GUI.

My Qmainwindow gui have an `statusbar`.

Now i want a horizontal line at top of my statusbar so that it is shown separate from other widgets. (I want a horizontal line running for statusbar just like Toolbar as i have highlighted in red arrow ).

I have attached the picture for it.
[image: Statisbar horizontal line shown in RED]

Comment: Could you provide your code so we can see your structure

Comment: code is bit large in size but .. i am using default status bar settings in QT .. displaying mesage by following code ...     ui->statusBar->showMessage("hello");

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qstatusbar)?

Comment: ok .. but is it not possible to do with QT creator statusbar property ... ?

Comment: I am using following code to format the statusbar ... but its giving me error ... ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet(QStatusBar {
                                 background: brown;
                             );

Comment: I missed the double quotes..  ... its working ... ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet("QStatusBar {
                                 background: brown}"
                             );

Comment: but still it is completely changing the background colour .. but does not show the border

Comment: When i use following code, style is not adding border to the statusbar ............. ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet(" QStatusBar::item { border: 1px solid red;                                                      border-radius: 3px }");

Comment: got it working.. border is created ... ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet("QStatusBar { border: 1px solid grey;}");

Comment: still one thing that border of statusbar is drawn dark .. what colour should i put so that border comes exactly like border of my toolbar ... please suggest ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a stylesheet to set a top-border to your `QStatusBar` widget:

```
setStyleSheet("QStatusBar{border-top: 1px outset grey;}");
```